# Sign Test Exercise

Tags: r, statistics

I'm having trouble finding the p-value on this non-parametrical statistics exercise (located in the Signed Rank Statistic section).

This is the exercise:

> https://ibb.co/M2n4jxM

I tried to apply the SIGN.test, using the following code in R, but seems to be wrong

```
Cr=c(17.4,17.9,17.6,18.1,17.6,18.9,16.9,17.5,17.8,17.4,24.6,26.0)
SIGN.test(Cr,y=NULL,md=18,alternative="two.sided",0.936)

Results
s = 4, p-value = 0.3877
```

The answer, according to my teacher, would be: p-value:.734.

Anyone can give me a second opinion about the exercise?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, some comments which I hope will be helpful. (1) People responding to your question won't want to look at the exercise in a link. (2) Try assigning the result of SIGN.test to some variable (say, `SIGN.test(<stuff goes here>) -> foo`) and then `dput(foo)` to see all the details. In particular, look at the test statistic. Does the test statistic have the value you expected to see? With the test statistic in hand, can you figure out the p-value from a published list? (3) Conceptual questions about statistics are better suited to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The SIGN.test function is from the BSDA package. Please indicate the use of non-standard packages in your questions.

Comment: @RobertDodier , thank you. I'm new here in StackOverflow. The next time I will follow your advice :).
I didn't know about stats.stackexchange. I will look at there right now. Thank you